# Creating multi-step form using angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to create multi step form using angularjs.
Here is the code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("gameManagement", ["ui.router", "ngAnimate", "ngResource", "toaster"])

        .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterPorvider) {
            $urlRouterPorvider.otherwise("/Game/Home");

            $stateProvider
                .state("Home", {
                    url: "/Game/Home",
                    templateUrl: "/app/Game/GameView.html",
                    controller: "GameController as vm"
                });

            $stateProvider
                .state("Log", {
                    url: "/Game/Log",
                    templateUrl: "/app/Log/GameLogView.html",
                    controller: "GameLogController as vm"
                });

            $stateProvider
             .state("MultiStepForm", {
                 url: "/Game/MuiltyStepForm",
                 templateUrl: "/app/MultiStepForm/MuiltyStepForm.html"
             });

            $stateProvider
              .state("MultiStepForm.view", {
                  url: "/Game/MuiltyStepForm/view",
                  templateUrl: "/app/MultiStepForm/MuiltyStepForm.html"
              })

             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step1', {
                 url: '/step1',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep1.html'
             })
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step2', {
                 url: '/step2',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep2.html'
             })
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step3', {
                 url: '/step3',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep3.html'
             })
        }]);
})();
```

I get this error when I try to move to state **MultiStepForm.view.step2**

**Error: Could not resolve '.MultiStepForm.view.step2' from state 'MultiStepForm.view'**

Any idea why I get the error?

And can I create nested state inside nested state?

Comment: was the answer helpful to you or is their something else wrong. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is because you are using nested states so in your example

```
.state('MultiStepForm.view.step1', {
                 url: '/step1',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep1.html'
             })
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step2', {
                 url: '/step2',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep2.html'
             })
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step3', {
                 url: '/step3',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep3.html'
             })
```

step2 inherits from step1 and not from multistepform.view

I think you should be able to fix it by doing this :

```
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step1', {
                 url: '/step1',
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep1.html'
             })
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step2', {
                 url: '/step2',
                 parent: MultiStepForm.view,
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep2.html'
             })
             .state('MultiStepForm.view.step3', {
                 url: '/step3',
                 parent: MultiStepForm.view,
                 templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/FormStep3.html'
             })
```

check out this url for more info about nested states [nested views in angular](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)